# Is it possible to assign an ID to a ViewBag in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, viewbag

Hello I'm trying to assign an ID to a ViewBag and I'm not sure if it's possible.

I have a for loop that cycles through my sites db.

```
float[] osiTotal = new float[sites.Count + 1];
foreach (Site s in sites)
{  
       osiTotal[s.ID] = osiPartCost[s.ID] + osiCompCost[s.ID] + osiItemCost[s.ID];
       ViewBag.OSITotal[s.ID] = osiTotal[s.ID];
}
```

Then on the view page it looks like this

```
foreach (Site s in sites)
{ 
    <tr>
          <td>Total</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>@ViewBag.OffReportTotal[s.ID]</td>
    </tr>
}
```

But this gives me "Cannot perform runtime binding on a nullable reference" error message so I am wanting to know if what I am trying to do is possible?

Comment: Find your nullable reference and make it non-nullable using the ?? operator.

Comment: Why are you using ViewBag instead of creating a strongly typed Model?

Comment: That will compile since viewbag is dynamic, but unless you instantiate OSITotals as an array before you start assigning to it, it will be null. Also what @Igor said.

Comment: sorry I just didn't include it in the code. I have instantiated it as an array already. I have added it into my question. And I'm new to MVC so still figuring things out. I didn't think I would have to make a full model to just return a value. I thought this would be the simpler way to do it @MattEvans

Comment: Good rule of thumb when using MVC: avoid ViewBag. Almost everything you need to do can be done via the Model.